# Marshmallow permission Android

Tags: android

I am currently working on an application that requires several "dangerous" permissions.

So I tried adding `"ask for permission"` as required in Android Marshmallow(API Level 23), and its working fine.

now user can see all related permission of app in setting screen(App Permission option).

1. What happen if user toggle off permission from setting screen and how to prevent user to toggle off that?
2. If so is there any broadcast fire when user do that?

According to my need I want to prevent user to toggle off runtime permission  from setting screen, is it possible or not?

Comment: No, you can not prevent that. You have to check if permission is granted or not, each time you need that permission.

Comment: You should call `checkSelfPermission` for the relevant permissions _at the point where you need those permissions_, not when your app starts or something like that.

Comment: You should check permission where you need that everytime like if you want permission for camera just ask before your method called even if he toggle off before calling the method it check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what happen if user toggle off permission from setting screen

Your process is terminated. When your code runs again, you would have to ask for the permission, just as you do when your app first runs.

> how to prevent user to toggle off that?

Don't write an Android app that uses `dangerous` permissions.

> i want to prevent user to toggle off runtime permission from setting screen, is it possible or not?

Fortunately, no.

Comment: kk understood well thanks...actually i know well about runtime permission but only wanted to know that to prevent user to toggle off from setting screen . thanks @commonsWare

Comment: and one more thing that means we also cannot hide the all showing dangerous permission in setting screen (App permissions setting screen)?

Comment: @aj0822ArpitJoshi: Correct.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare and there is no any broadcast fire when toggle off and on so we can detect that in our app ?